# R: Append multiple rows to dataframe within for-loop

Tags: r, append, text-mining

I have PDF files that I made from these wikipedia pages (for example):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-120_AMRAAM

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIM-9_Sidewinder

I have a list of keywords I want to search for within the document and extract the sentences in which they appear.

```
keywords <- c("altitude", "range", "speed")
```

I can call the file, extract the text from the PDF, pull the sentences with the keywords from the PDF.  This works if I do this with each of the keywords individually, but when I try to do this in a loop I keep getting this issue where the rows aren't appending.  Instead it's almost doing a cbind and then an error gets thrown regarding the number of columns.  Here is my code and any help you can provide as to what I can do to make this work is much appreciated.

How do I get the rows to append correctly and appear in one file per PDF?

```
pdf.files <- list.files(path = "/path/to/file", pattern = "*.pdf", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(pdf.files)) {
    for (j in 1:length(keywords)) {
        text <- pdf_text(file.path("path", "to", "file", pdf.files[i]))
        text2 <- tolower(text)
        text3 <- gsub("\r", "", text2)
        text4 <- gsub("\n", "", text3)
        text5 <- grep(keywords[j], unlist(strsplit(text4, "\\.\\s+")), value = TRUE)
    }
    temp <- rbind(text5)
    assign(pdf.files[i], temp)
}
```

After I get the rows to append correctly the next step will be to add in the keywords as a variable to the left of the extracted sentences.  Example of ideal output:

```
keywords   sentence

altitude   sentence1.1
altitude   sentence1.2
range      sentence2.1
range      sentence2.2
range      sentence2.3
speed      sentence3.1
speed      sentence3.2
```

Would this be done in the loop as well or post as a separate function?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it took some real thinking but I made it work and it's not pretty but it gets the job done:

```
# This first part initializes the files to be written to
files <- list.files(path = "/path/to/file", pattern = "*.*", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
for (h in 1:length(files)) {
    temp1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
    x <- c("Title", "x")
    colnames(temp1) <- x
    write.table(temp1, paste0("/path/to/file", tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[h]), ".txt"), sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
# This next part fills in the files with the sentences
pdf.files <- list.files(path = "/path/to/file", pattern = "*.pdf", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(pdf.files)) {
    for (j in 1:length(keywords)) {
        text <- pdf_text(file.path("path", "to", "file", pdf.files[i]))
        text2 <- tolower(text)
        text3 <- gsub("\r", "", text2)
        text4 <- gsub("\n", "", text3)
        text5 <- as.data.frame(grep(keywords[j], unlist(strsplit(text4, "\\.\\s+")), value = TRUE))
        colnames(text5) <- "x"
        if (nrow(text5) != 0) {
            title <- as.data.frame(keywords[j])
            colnames(title) <- "Title"
            temp <- cbind(title, text5)
            temp <- unique(temp)
            write.table(temp, paste0("/path/to/file", tools::file_path_sans_ext(pdf.files[i]), ".txt"), sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
        }
    }
}
```